# Why doesn't the following prototype declaration work?

Tags: javascript, arrays, prototype

I have declared Array prototype myArrayMax and the code seems right after repeated verifications from other resources on w3schools.com :

The code is for finding the maximum number in a given array.

Yet, it doesn't work, and the console shows the following error message:

> Uncaught TypeError: points.myArrayMax is not a function

I can't find the problem in this prototype declaration

```js
var points = [40, 100, 1, 5, 25, 10];
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = points.myArrayMax();

var len, max;

Array.prototype.myArrayMax = function() {
  len = this.length;
  max = -Infinity;
  while (len--) {
    if (this[len] > max) {
      max = this[len];
    }
  }
  return max;
}
```

```html
<h2>JavaScript Array Sort</h2>

<p>The highest number is <span id="demo"></span>.</p>
```

Comment: There's no reason to make `len` and `max` globals here.

Comment: @Quentin, is there a serious problem in declaring vars as global (like over here there is no possibilty of conflict)

Comment: No possibility of conflict until you write another function which uses a variable called `max` or `len` … which aren't exactly uncommon names. Best practise is to use the narrowest scope possible for variables.

Comment: @AthaSSiN I'll flip the question on you - is there a particular *reason* you need them to be global?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you're attempting to use `Array.myArrayMax` **before** you actually define it.

```js
var points = [40, 100, 1, 5, 25, 10];

var len, max;

Array.prototype.myArrayMax = function() {
  len = this.length;
  max = -Infinity;
  while (len--) {
    if (this[len] > max) {
      max = this[len];
    }
  }
  return max;
}

console.log(points.myArrayMax());
```

Comment: And as Quintin said: _There's no reason to make len and max globals here_